# Open component with Onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to open a component when I click in a wager name, but when I do nothing is happening. I don't know what else I need to make it work, hope someone can help me.

```
wagerSwitch(param) {
        switch(param) {
            case 'Win':
                return <WPS/>;
            case 'Place':
                return <WPS/>;
            case 'Show':
                return <WPS/>;
            case 'Exacta':
                return <Exacta/>;
            case 'Quinella':
                return <Quinella/>;
            case 'Trifecta':
                return <Trifecta/>;
            case 'Superfecta':
                return <Superfecta/>;
            case 'Double1':
                return <Double/>;
            case 'FDouble2':
                return <Double/>;
            case 'Pick3-1':
                return <Pick3/>;
            case 'Pick3-3':
                return <Pick3/>;
            case 'Pick4-1':
                return <Pick4/>;
            case 'Pick4-4':
                return <Pick4/>;
            case 'Pick6-1':
                return <Pick6/>;
            case 'Pick6-6':
                return <Pick6/>;
            default:
                return <WPS/>;
        }
    }
```

**Condition with onclick in my render method**

```
const wagers = this.state.WagerTypes;
        const wagerList= [];

        if(wagers){
            wagers.forEach((wager) =>{
                wagerList.push(
                    <span className="label label-default" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} key={wager['name']}onClick={() => this.wagerSwitch(wager.name)}>
                        {wager.name}
                    </span>
                );
            });
        }
```

I need to open the component when I click in a wager name to show the entrys of each wager

Comment: What you return from the `onClick` handler will not be rendered. You need to update the component state in such a way that you can derive if a component should be rendered for a particular wager after it has been clicked.

Comment: can you plz make a example... please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you return from the `onClick` handler will not be rendered. You need to update the component state in such a way that you can derive if a component should be rendered for a particular wager after it has been clicked.

One way of going about it is to add a new property called e.g. `isClicked` to each wager object in the `WagerTypes` array and toggle that property between true and false on click.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    WagerTypes: [
      /* ... */
    ]
  };

  wagerSwitch(param) {
    // ...
  }

  onClick = wager => {
    this.setState(({ WagerTypes }) => ({
      WagerTypes: WagerTypes.map(w =>
        w === wager ? { ...w, isClicked: !w.isClicked } : w
      )
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.WagerTypes.map(wager => (
          <span
            className="label label-default"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            key={wager.name}
            onClick={() => this.onClick(wager)}
          >
            {wager.name}
            {wager.isClicked ? wagerSwitch(wager.name) : null}
          </span>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't add a isClicked property because I'm getting the data from a API

Comment: @JoseCarlosRodriguezArrieta You can add it before you put the API data in state. `this.setState({ WagerTypes: response.data.map(w => ({ ...w, isClicked: false })) });`